# API value in range?

Tags: python, django, api, range

I'm new to django and to python. I'm trying to re-create an air condition app in django.

Due to the fact my APIs haven't a good, moderate etc. condition I would like to set a range for the number..

Example:

- 50-100 = GOOD
- 100-200 = moderate

etc.

I was trying to do something like:

```
{% if api.data.aqi in range(0, 50) %}
    <p>Good</p>
{% elif api.data.aqi in range(50, 100) %}
    <p>Moderate</p>
```

But of course I get this error. Is there anyone who can help me?

```
Template error:
In template C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\weather\lookup\templates\home.html, error at line 16
   Could not parse the remainder: '(50,' from 'range(50,'
   6 : 
   7 : 
   8 : <br/>
   9 : {% if api %}
   10 :     {% if api == "Error..." %}
   11 :         C'è stato un errore, prova di nuovo.
   12 :     {% else %}
   13 : 
   14 :         <div class="jumbotron">
   15 :           <h1 class="display-4">
   16 :                  {% if api.data.aqi.filter in range(50, 100) %} 
   17 :                 <p>Buono</p>
   18 :                 
   19 : 
   20 :                 {% elif api.data.aqi in range (51, 100) %}
   21 :                 <p>Moderato</p>
   22 :                 
   23 : 
   24 : 
   25 :           </h1>
   26 :           <p class="lead">Qualità dell'aria in {{ api.data.city.name }} al momento: {{ api.data.aqi }}</p>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\smartif.py", line 175, in translate_token
    op = OPERATORS[token]

During handling of the above exception ('range(50,'), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\weather\lookup\views.py", line 15, in home
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'api': api})
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 15, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 29, in get_template
    return Template(
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 194, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 477, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 475, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 266, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 477, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 475, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 209, in do_block
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock',))
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 477, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 475, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 952, in do_if
    nodelist = parser.parse(('elif', 'else', 'endif'))
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 477, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 475, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 966, in do_if
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endif',))
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 477, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 475, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 951, in do_if
    condition = TemplateIfParser(parser, bits).parse()
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 884, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\smartif.py", line 166, in __init__
    mapped_tokens.append(self.translate_token(token))
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\smartif.py", line 177, in translate_token
    return self.create_var(token)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 887, in create_var
    return TemplateLiteral(self.template_parser.compile_filter(value), value)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 562, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "C:\Users\Cavre\Progetti\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 661, in __init__
    raise TemplateSyntaxError("Could not parse the remainder: '%s' "

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: '(50,' from 'range(50,'
```

Comment: api.data.aqi it's the number of the AQI of the air and I get that number from the APIs that's why I need the "in range" function

Comment: "I get an error" is insufficient problem description.

Comment: I get TemplateSyntaxError on the line corrispondent to {% if api.data.aqi in range(0, 50) %}

Comment: You should probably include all the information you have about your error in your question.